# Why TypeError: axios.create is not a function? When testing axios GET

Tags: unit-testing, testing, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm trying to test my axios API functions in React.

Found this question here: [how do i test axios in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest) which pointed to using `axios-mock-adapter`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import chatbot from './chatbot';

describe('Chatbot', () => {
    it('returns data when sendMessage is called', done => {
        var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        const data = { response: true };
        mock.onGet('https://us-central1-hutoma-backend.cloudfunctions.net/chat').reply(200, data);

        chatbot.sendMessage(0, 'any').then(response => {
            expect(response).toEqual(data);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

---

The real function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve all Akamai images
 * @param  {String} akamai Akamai url
 * @return {Thenable}      Resolved: Akamai images
 */
export const callGetAkamai = () =>
  makeRequest('/akamai', 'GET')
    .catch(defaultCatch('callGetAkamai'));
```

My test:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import { callGetAkamai } from './api';

describe('GetAkamai', () => {
  it('returns data when callGetAkamai is called', (done) => {
    console.log('MockAdapter', MockAdapter);
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    // const mock = axios.create({
    //   baseURL: 'https://us-central1-hutoma-backend.cloudfunctions.net/chat/'
    // });

    const data = { response: true };
    mock.onGet('https://us-central1-hutoma-backend.cloudfunctions.net/chat').reply(200, data);

    callGetAkamai().then((response) => {
      expect(response).toEqual(data);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: this helped me https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/issues/58#issuecomment-542819088

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you mocking `axios` already? I have run into this issue myself, and after looking in all the wrong places, I realized I was already mocking `axios` with `jest`.

Put the following snippet in your [setupTestFrameworkScriptFile](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string):

```
const mockNoop = () => new Promise(() => {});

// Notice how `create` was not being mocked here...
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  default: mockNoop,
  get: mockNoop,
  post: mockNoop,
  put: mockNoop,
  delete: mockNoop,
  patch: mockNoop
}));
```

While you might be able to do both, if you are using the `axios-mock-adapter`, you might want to remove your other mocks (and skip the snippet above).

Comment: Do you do this in the test file itself or in like `__mocks__/axios.ts` that go like this: `export default { create: () => new Promise(() => {} ) }`

Comment: Good question, I updated the snippet above, but you would put in the `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it myself. I answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51414152/73323

Comment: Also good to know: Even if the whole __mocks__/axios.ts is commented out, jest still mocks it! Deleting the file solved it for me.

Answer (score 11):

Adding this here since it's the first hit on google to the question and the answer selected doesn't really answer the question.

This problem typically happens when you are already mocking axios (very likely within a `__mocks__` folder.

With jest, you can explicitly unmock, then call this `axios-mock-adapter`.

```
jest.unmock('axios');
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
...
```

`axios-mock-adapter` gives nice, flexible apis when working with external requests. However it doesn't globally prevent your app from making external calls that can be triggered by a test in a different component.

So I found both using `axios-mock-adapter` and doing a manual mock in the `__mocks__` folder equally helpful.

Comment: i used jest.unmock('axios'); and it solved the problem. So now my tests are running but the test is failing, so the moch is not working

Comment: @asma after unmocking, did you do the import in the same file? You'd need to re-mock in the file you unmocked. Wondering if that was done?

Comment: yes i did the import and the mock, but its not working

Comment: @asma same for me. Did you figure out the issue yet

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte not really, i postponed the issue.

Comment: @Cent Could you please share a working code snippet? Facing the same issue. axios. create is not a functions error is gone but  Mocking is not working.

Comment: @LAXITKUMAR did you sove the issue?

Comment: No couldn't find the solution @The Dead Man

Comment: Here's a few things to keep in mind. First, if you add `axios.js` to `__mocks__`, even if the file is empty, Jest will mock `axios` anyway (maybe as undefined).
Second, if axios is mocked already, for example in `__mocks__`, `axios-mock-adapter` will throw the error `axios.create is not a function'. You can use `jest.unmock('axios')` to solve this for a targeted use case. Third, `axios-mock-adapter` lets you mock the axios object (exported from 'axios'), or an axios instance from `axios.create()`.  I would have used bullets here but SO mini-markdown doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to the fact that you are using a new instance of axios with a custom config **axios.create([config])**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

But in the test you are testing axios

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
```

If you are creating a new axios instance, then you need to test it, but not axios itself.

```
const mock = new MockAdapter(instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't mocking `axios` and you don't want to, you can use `babel-jest` to transform `axios` code (`babel-jest` is shipped with `jest` out of the box). In `jest` configuration:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!axios)",
],
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": [
    "babel-jest", {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
    }
  ],
}
```

Based on https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11783#issuecomment-1107861603.

For more information on code transformation, see `jest` documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation.

Also, make sure to use the latest version of `axios-mock-adapter`.