# react-testing-library mocking axios.create({}) instance

Tags: reactjs, mocking, axios, react-testing-library

I want to test my api with [react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)
And I exporting the instance created by axios.create from a file called apiClient.ts

```html
import axios from 'axios'

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  responseType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})

export default apiClient
```

Then use the axios instances I get from apiClient in my users.ts fetchUsersApi

```html
import apiClient from './apiClient'

export interface ITrader {
  id: number
  name: string
  username: string
  email: string
  address: any
  phone: string
  website: string
  company: any
}

export const fetchTradersApi = async (): Promise<ITrader[]> => {
  const response = await apiClient.get<ITrader[]>('/users')
  return response.data
}
```

I created a **mocks** folder and added axios.ts in it

```html
export default {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
}
```

My users.spec.tsx looks like:

```html
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import axiosMock from 'axios'
import { fetchTradersApi } from './traders'

jest.mock('axios')

describe.only('fetchTradersApi', () => {
  
  afterEach(cleanup)
  it('Calls axios and returns traders', async () => {
    axiosMock.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: ['Jo Smith'],
      })
    )
    const traders = await fetchTradersApi()
    expect(traders).toBe([{ name: 'Jo Smith' }])
    expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users`)
  })
})
```

I run my test and I get:
Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: _axios.default.create is not a function

  1 | import axios from 'axios'
  2 |
> 3 | const apiClient = axios.create({
```

Please help me on solving the issue by creating a proper axios mock that work with react-testing-library, Tnx in advance.

Comment: I tried few different ways to mock the "create" function on my fake version of axios but I couldn't  make to work.   I also tried solution suggested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413937/why-typeerror-axios-create-is-not-a-function-when-testing-axios-get?noredirect=1&lq=1  but I received can't get data of undefined

Comment: My implementation and tests were based on the youtube tutorial example: React Testing Library - Testing a mock Axios request. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ngj2f1n9pUw&list=PL8fumNHsC-3NaPNxh2bous6bBDWwJ4r1-&index=6  and since my fetch function implementation is a different a bit because I am using the returned instance of axios.create instead of using directly axios.get directly I tried  tweaked the mock to include the create function in the axios mock but with no luck.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155045/react-testing-library-mocking-axios-create-instance/66566021#66566021) could be a solution.

Answer (score 4):

After spending an entire day I found a solution for the exact same problem which I was having. The problem which I was having is related to JEST, Node and Typescript combo. Let me brief about the files which are playing role in this:

1. axios-instance.ts   // initializing axios
2. api.ts              // api controller
3. api.spec.ts         // api test files

**axios-instance.ts**

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://example-path/products/`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

**api.ts**

```
"use strict";

import {Request, Response, RequestHandler, NextFunction} from "express";
import axiosInstance from "./axios-instance";

/**
 * POST /:productId
 * Save product by productId
 */
export const save: RequestHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const response = await axiosInstance.post(`${req.params.id}/save`, req.body);
        res.status(response.status).json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(error.response.status).json(error.response.data);
    }
};
```

**api.spec.ts**

```
import { save } from "./api";
import axiosInstance from "./axios-instance";

describe.only("controller", () => {

    describe("test save", () => {

        let mockPost: jest.SpyInstance;

        beforeEach(() => {
            mockPost = jest.spyOn(axiosInstance, 'post');
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            jest.clearAllMocks();
        });

        it("should save data if resolved [200]", async () => {

            const req: any = {
                params: {
                    id: 5006
                },
                body: {
                    "productName": "ABC",
                    "productType": "Food",
                    "productPrice": "1000"
                }
            };
            const res: any = {
                status: () => {
                    return {
                        json: jest.fn()
                    }
                },
            };
            const result = {
                status: 200,
                data: {
                    "message": "Product saved"
                }
            };

            mockPost.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(result));

            await save(req, res, jest.fn);

            expect(mockPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mockPost.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
            const mockResult = await mockPost.mock.results[0].value;
            expect(mockResult).toStrictEqual(result);
        });

        it("should not save data if rejected [500]", async () => {

            const req: any = {
                params: {
                    id: 5006
                },
                body: {}
            };
            const res: any = {
                status: () => {
                    return {
                        json: jest.fn()
                    }
                },
            };
            const result = {
                response: {
                    status: 500,
                    data: {
                        "message": "Product is not supplied"
                    }
                }
            };

            mockPost.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(result));

            await save(req, res, jest.fn);

            expect(mockPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
            const calls = mockPost.mock.calls.length;
            expect(calls).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```

For the posted requirement we have to mock the "axiosInstance" not the actual "axios" object from the library as we are doing our calling from axiosInstance.

In the spec file we have imported the axiosInstance not the actual axios

```
import axiosInstance from "./axios-instance";
```

Then we have created a spy for the post method (get/post/put anything you can spy)

```
let mockPost: jest.SpyInstance;
```

Initializing in before each so that each test case will have a fresh spy to start with and also clearing the mocks are needed after each.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    mockPost = jest.spyOn(axiosInstance, 'post');
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

Mocking the implementation resolved/reject

```
mockPost.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(result));
mockPost.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(result));
```

Then calling the actual method

```
await save(req, res, jest.fn);
```

Checking for the expected results

```
expect(mockPost).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(mockPost.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
const mockResult = await mockPost.mock.results[0].value;
expect(mockResult).toStrictEqual(result);
```

Hope it helps and you can relate the solution with your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe is too late to register my answer, but it can help others.

What has happened in this case is the context. Your apiClient function runs in another context, so one of the ways is to mock your apiClient instead of the Axios library.

```js
...
import apiClient from 'path-to-your-apiClient';

jest.mock('path-to-your-apiClient');

const mockedApi = apiClient as jest.Mocked<typeof apiClient>;
```

Now, let's make some changes to your **api.spec.ts**:

```js
import { save } from "./api";
import axiosInstance from "./axios-instance";

import apiClient from 'path-to-your-apiClient';

jest.mock('path-to-your-apiClient');

const mockedApi = apiClient as jest.Mocked<typeof apiClient>;

describe.only("controller", () => {

    describe("test save", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
      mockedApi.post.mockeResolvedValue({ your-defalt-value }) // if you need
    })

        it("should save data if resolved [200]", async () => {

            const req: any = {
                params: {
                    id: 5006
                },
                body: {
                    "productName": "ABC",
                    "productType": "Food",
                    "productPrice": "1000"
                }
            };
            const res: any = {
                status: () => {
                    return {
                        json: jest.fn()
                    }
                },
            };
            const result = {
                status: 200,
                data: {
                    "message": "Product saved"
                }
            };

            mockedApi.post.mockResolvedValue(result);

            await save(req, res, jest.fn);

            expect(mockedApi.post).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mockedApi.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            ... // add may assertions as you want
        });

        ....
    });
});
```

Hope this piece of code can help others.