# Jest mock on function typescript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

It is really painful here when I write test in Typescript. I have my function in api

api.ts

```
export getModel = () => {...} //return a promise
```

And when I try to mock it with Jest. I got the error: property mockRejectedValueOnce does not exist on type ...

```
import {getModel as mockGetModel} from './api'

jest.mock('./api, () => {
    return {getModel: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())}
})

it('should ...', () => {
  mockGetModel.mockRejectedValueOnce('hello') //error here
})
```

I try to cast it, either as any, and I get the error

`TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

Try many ways but I still cannot mock the function with Jest. Could you guys show me the correct way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already install the `@types/jest` package? `mockRejestedValueOnce` should be `mockRejectedValueOnce`.

Comment: yes I have installed types for Jest

Comment: Is `mockGetRequest` it another mocked function? or it's the `mockGetModel`?

Comment: Thanks for editting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript and Jest: Avoiding type errors on mocked functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions)

Comment: If you're only mocking one function it is often easiest to use `jest.spyOn` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583610/10149510)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to cast it with `jest.Mock` type.

```js
let mockGetRequest = getRequest as jest.Mock<any>
```

because Typescript doesn't know that you mocked the `getModel` after calling the `jest.mock`

Comment: then when I use mockedGetModel.mockRejectedValueOnce("hello"). I get another error: TS2345: Argument of type '"hello"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

Comment: Update your answer then I will accept it

 `let mockGetRequest = getRequest as jest.Mock<any>`