# How to make TSServer recognize when jest.mock() is used?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a javascript project with `jsconfig.json` configured properly. It works for almost everything except for when I mock a module with `jest.mock()` on my unit tests:

```
// unit.test.js

jest.mock('./api')

it('does something', () => {
  // Linting error:  
  // Property 'mockResolvedValue' does not exist on type () => Promise<any>
  api.loadStudents.mockResolvedValue([]);
});
```

Is there any way to let TSServer know that Jest is mocking this module, so the exported object properties are instances of `jest.Mock`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you found the solution to this yet, but I ran across a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions) that solves this problem. In a nutshell, you create a new reference to the thing you're mocking (`api`) that you explicitly typecast as of type `jest.Mocked<...>`.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not using Typescript. I'm using Javascript with the `jsconfig.json`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread your question.