# How to mock with strict TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

For example:

```
let mockhttp; // 1

beforeEach(() => {
    mockhttp = { //3
        get: jest.fn()
    };

    mockhttp.get.mockReturnValue(of(...)); //4
});

it('should fetch', async () => {
    const service = new MyService(mockhttp as any as HttpClient); //2
});
```

This will give the following error on 1 and 2.

```
Variable 'mockhttp' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
```

Changing `let mockhttp;` to `let mockhttp: HttpClient;`

Gives on 3:

```
Type '{ get: Mock ; }' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpClient': handler, request, delete, head, and 5 more.
```

and on 4:

```
TS2339: Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type '{ (url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; context?: HttpContext; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | ... 1 more ... | boolean)[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType: "arraybuffer"; withCred...'
```

Is there a way to solve this without adding `//@ts-ignore` everywhere?

Note: this question is not about testing the httpclient or anything related. It is just for demo purpose. It could be any other service or component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript and Jest: Avoiding type errors on mocked functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495473/typescript-and-jest-avoiding-type-errors-on-mocked-functions)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Related, but does not solve it.

Comment: Then please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't explain how the proposed dupe fails to answer your question.

Comment: There is not much to explain, the same error appears.

Comment: Great, then it should be easy to add: I read <link>, I did <code>, but still get <error>.

Answer (score -1):

Angular provides a nice package for testing HTTP communication.

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  }));
```

Here is a nice article with examples: [Testing Angular HTTP Communication](https://itnext.io/testing-angular-http-communication-9a120a10da18).

Comment: This question is not about testing the HttpClient

Comment: sorry, I didn't restrict myself from stopping reinvention of a wheel (:

Comment: @RobinDijkhof the HttpClientTestingModule isn't about testing the HttpClient, but testing things that _use_ it, which is what you seem to be doing. See https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests