# Jest testing for axios request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, axios

I am new to react js and node js. I have a code which connects to a back-end service to fetch data. Now i need to write unit test to it using jest js. Below is the code i need to test:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const {host, token} = require('./config');

const getData = async (req, mainRes) => {
 try {
  let token = await token();
  let {data} = await axios({
   method: 'GET',
   url: `${host}/api/books`,
   headers: {
     Authorization: `${token}`
   }
 });
 mainRes.status(200).json(data);
 } catch (error) {
  errorHandler(error.message, mainRes);
 }
```

};

Below is the test file:

```
jest.mock('axios');

const axios = require('axios');
const {host, token} = require('./config');
const file = require('../file');
```

How to test the rest of the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test axios in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const { host, token } = require('./config');
const { errorHandler } = require('./errorHandler');

export const getData = async (req, mainRes) => {
  try {
    let tk = await token();
    let { data } = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `${host}/api/books`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${tk}`,
      },
    });
    mainRes.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    errorHandler(error.message, mainRes);
  }
};
```

`errorHandler.js`:

```js
export const errorHandler = (message, mRes) => null;
```

`config.js`:

```js
export async function token() {
  return '123';
}

export const host = 'localhost';
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import * as mod from '.';
const { token } = require('./config');
const axios = require('axios');
const { errorHandler } = require('./errorHandler');

jest.mock('./config', () => {
  const config = require.requireActual('./config');
  return { token: jest.fn(), host: config.host };
});

jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn());
jest.mock('./errorHandler', () => {
  return { errorHandler: jest.fn() };
});

describe('60823714', () => {
  it('should get books', async () => {
    token.mockResolvedValueOnce('abc');
    axios.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { books: [] } });
    const mReq = {};
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), json: jest.fn() };
    await mod.getData(mReq, mRes);
    expect(token).toBeCalled();
    expect(axios).toBeCalledWith({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'localhost/api/books',
      headers: { Authorization: `abc` },
    });
    expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(200);
    expect(mRes.json).toBeCalledWith({ books: [] });
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    token.mockResolvedValueOnce('abc');
    const mError = new Error('network');
    axios.mockRejectedValueOnce(mError);
    const mReq = {};
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), json: jest.fn() };
    await mod.getData(mReq, mRes);
    expect(token).toBeCalled();
    expect(axios).toBeCalledWith({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'localhost/api/books',
      headers: { Authorization: `abc` },
    });
    expect(errorHandler).toBeCalledWith('network', mRes);
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60823714/index.test.js
  60823714
    ✓ should get books (6ms)
    ✓ should handle error (2ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   93.75 |      100 |   66.67 |   90.91 |                   
 config.js |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 2                 
 index.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.876s, estimated 7s
```