# How to mock VueAxios in jest

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, axios

I want to test my Api functions which are on separate file outside vue component. Inside this methods i call api by Vue.axios, and i can't find the way to mock and test it like in this post:

[How do I test axios in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest/51654713#51654713)

example method:

```
cancelAuction: function (auction_id) {
    if (validateApiInt(auction_id)) {
      return Vue.axios.delete(`/auctions/${auction_id}`);
    }
    return {};
  },
```

example usage:

```
const response = await AuctionApi.cancelAuction(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok that was pretty obvious. I had to mock whole Vue like below:

```
jest.mock('vue', () => ({
  axios: {
    get: jest.fn()
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start learning Jest + @vue/test-utils. Here is a simple example for those people want to mock "vue-axios".

```
// @/components/Helloword.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Email: <span>{{ email }}</span></h1>
    <button @click="fetchData">Get Random Email</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      const res = (await this.axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')).data
        .results[0].email;
      this.email = res;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

--

```
    // test/unit/example.spec.js

import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: () =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        results: [{ email: 'mockAxios@email.com' }],
      },
    }),
}));

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('click and fetch data...', async (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, {
      mocks: {
        axios,
      },
    });

    await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');

    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toContain('@');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```