# Need some resources and help on testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have been asked to write a test suite on a series of async functions in React Native. One function for example reads as follows...

```
export const refreshAuth = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    getRefreshToken()
      .then(refreshJWT =>
        axios.post(`${SomeAPI.auth}/refresh`, {
          refreshJWT
        })
      )
      .then((res: AxiosResponse<JWTData>) => {
        onSignIn(res.data.accessJWT, res.data.refreshJWT);
        resolve(res.data.accessJWT);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('failed to refresh the access token', err);
        reject(err);
      })
  );

export const getRefreshToken = () => SecureStore.getItemAsync(REFRESH_KEY);
```

How would you properly test this function using Jest?

Comment: You should use https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async for docs on Promises, and something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest to mock the server requests.

Comment: How did you `import` `SecureStore` module? Please provide the code

Comment: Just standard import from expo-secure-store.