# React testing error "Cannot read get property of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I am trying to test the function `searchTrigger` in my `CardMain` component.

```
export default class CardMain extends Component {

    state = {
        Pools : [],
        loading: false,
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/pools')
        .then (res => {
                //console.log(res.data.data);
                this.setState({
                    Pools: res.data.data,
                    loading: true,
                    message: "Loading..."
                },()=>{
                    if (res && isMounted){
                        this.setState({
                            loading: false
                        });
                    }
                })
            }
        )
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    }

    


    // the function is for search method
    // upon search, this function is called and the state of the pools is changed
    searchTrigger = (search) => {

        Search = search.toLowerCase();

        SearchList = this.state.Pools.filter((e)=> {
            if (e.name.toLowerCase().includes(Search)){
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                })
                return e
            } 
        })

        if (SearchList.length === 0){
            this.setState({
                loading: true,
                message: "No pools found"
            })
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Searchbar trigger={this.searchTrigger}/>
                { this.state.loading ?
                 <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">{this.state.message}</div>   
                :<div>
                   {Search === "" ? <Card1 pools={this.state.Pools}/> : <Card1 pools={SearchList}/> }
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The function `searchTrigger` is passed to another class component called `Searchbar` which basically displays the search bar. Upon searching something, the function `searchTrigger` is called and the searched value is passed as an argument to this function.

So, I am trying to test this function and I am new to react and testing. I found some examples online and tried a simple testing whether the function is called or not. My `CardMain.test.js` code looks like this:

```
describe("callback function test", ()=> {
    it("runs it", () => {
        //const spy = jest.spyOn(CardMain.prototype,"searchTrigger");
        const cardmain = shallow(<CardMain/>)
        const spy = jest.spyOn(cardmain.instance(), "searchTrigger");
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
});
```

I get the **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined** pointing to the **axios.get("/pools")** in the `CardMain` component inside **componentDidMount**. `axios` is being imported from another component `api.js` which creates the instance of `axios` using `axios.create`. I have no idea what the problem is. I am very new to react. I have absolutely no idea, how do I test these components? Could somebody help me?

**Update:**

```
So, i tried mocking axios call:
let Wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
    Wrapper = shallow( <CardMain/>);
  });


describe("Card Main", ()=> {
    it("returns data when called", done => {
        let mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        const data = [{
            name: "Test",
            response: true
        }];
        mock.onGet('My_URL')
        .reply(200,data);
        const instance = Wrapper.instance();
        instance.componentDidMount().then(response => {
            expect(response).toEqual(data);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

It says "cannot read property .then of undefined"

Comment: You have to mock the `axios`. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest)

Comment: I tried mocking axios following the link. it says cannot read property .then of undefined. Updated axios test to the question above. Cannot i just test the function directly passing some values without mocking axios?

Comment: ok.. try this also -  ` import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');
axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockedData);`

Comment: `mockData` is nothing but your response