# mock axios with typescript react not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs

I'm trying to mock axios and test my component return data but I'm just getting nothing at the moment and I'm not sure why. I've created a test for the endpoint `fetchData` and called it `fetchData.test.ts` and I'm attempting to use that to mock axios within the `Products.test.tsx` component but right now I'm just getting an empty array.

Here are my failing test and error message:

Products.test.tsx

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';

import Products from '../components/Products';
import { cleanup, render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import {fetchData} from '../endpoints/fetchData'

import axios from 'axios';

import { data } from '../temp/data';

jest.mock('../endpoints/fetchData');

it('should show render data', async () => {
    const mockReults = data;

     await (fetchData as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue({
         mockReults
    })
    const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<Products />);

    
    await waitFor(() =>   expect(getByText('5-Minute Stories: In the Wild')).toBeInTheDocument() )

});
```

Error message for Products.test.tsx:

```
  ● should show render data

    Unable to find an element with the text: 5-Minute Stories: In the Wild. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          loading...
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

fetchData.test.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {fetchData} from '../endpoints/fetchData'
import { data } from '../temp/data';

jest.mock('axios');

it('should show render data', async () => {
    const setProducts = jest.fn()

    const mockResponse = {
        data
    }
    
    axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockResponse)

    const productsData = await fetchData(setProducts)

    expect(mockResponse.data).toEqual(productsData)


});
```

Here is the component I'm trying to test, I have a useEffect function and within it `setProducts` initiator which populates the data from fetchData into the state which ultimately loads the data onto the page:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { sortBy, sortSelectOptions } from '../utils/utils';
import { Products } from '../types/types';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import { fetchData } from '../endpoints/fetchData';
import { NoResults } from './NoResults';
import PlaceholderImage from '../../assets/spinner.gif';

import Select from './Select';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import '../index.css';

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Products[]>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [contentTypeValue, setContentTypeValue] = useState<string>('Stories');

  const productsPerPage = 20;
  const lastIndex = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - productsPerPage;
   const productsByContentType = products.filter((type: Products) => type.contentType.includes(contentTypeValue))  || products;
  const filteredProducts = sortBy?.[filterValue]?.(productsByContentType) ?? productsByContentType;
  
  const productsBySearchValue = filteredProducts.filter((search: Products) => {
    return search.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
  }) || filteredProducts;
  const currentProducts = productsBySearchValue.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
  const pages = Math.ceil(productsBySearchValue.length / productsPerPage);
  const numbers = [...Array(pages + 1).keys()].slice(1);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setProducts);
    setSearchValue('');
  }, []);

  if(products.length === 0) {
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }

  const nextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== lastIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(curr => curr + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== firstIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(curr => curr - 1);
    }
  };

  const movePages = (id: number) => {
    setCurrentPage(id);
  };


  //Generate content type list
  const transformContentTypeintoList = [
    ...new Set(products.map((prod) => prod.contentType).flat()),
  ];

  const contentTypeList = transformContentTypeintoList
    .map((item) =>  [
        {
          label: item,
          value: item,
        },
      ])
    .flat();

  const handleSort = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setFilterValue(event?.target.value);
    //goto page 1 after sort
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleTitleSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
        setSearchValue(value.toLowerCase());
        setCurrentPage(1)
  };

  const handleContentTypeSort = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setContentTypeValue(value) 
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const mapContentTypes = () => {
    return (
      <Select
        id="contentSelect"
        options={contentTypeList}
        datatestid={'contentTypeId'}
        onChange={handleContentTypeSort}
        defaultOption={'Select Content Type'}
        label={'Filter by Content type '}
      />
    );
  };
 
  const mapProducts = () => {
    if (currentProducts.length === 0) {
      return <NoResults />;
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="searchContainer">
            <TextInput
              className="searchInput"
              placeholder="search by title"
              value={searchValue}
              datatestid={'searchId'}
              onChange={handleTitleSearch}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="filterContainer">
              <div>
                <Pagination
                  numbers={numbers}
                  currentPage={currentPage}
                  prevPage={prevPage}
                  movePages={movePages}
                  nextPage={nextPage}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="filter">
                {mapContentTypes()}
                <Select
                  id="SortSelect"
                  options={sortSelectOptions}
                  datatestid={'sortTestId'}
                  onChange={handleSort}
                  defaultOption={'Sort by'}
                  label={'Sort by '}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            {currentProducts.map((product: Products) => {
              return (
                <div className="item" key={product.id}>
                  <LazyLoadImage
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                    placeholderSrc={PlaceholderImage}
                    src={product.imgSet.sm.src}
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <div
                    aria-label={`Product${product.id}`}
                    tabIndex={0}
                    className="innerContainer">
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Name`}>
                      Name: {product.title}
                    </span>
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Price`}>
                      Price: {product.price}
                    </span>
                    <span
                      className="text"
                      tabIndex={0}
                      aria-label={` Stock level`}>
                      Stock level: {product.productType}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <Pagination
              numbers={numbers}
              currentPage={currentPage}
              prevPage={prevPage}
              movePages={movePages}
              nextPage={nextPage}
            />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className="container">{mapProducts()}</div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This page above populated with data from this api: /endpoints/fetchData.ts

```
export const fetchData = async (setter: (arg0: any) => any) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3030/products');
    setter(res?.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

the data returned from the endpoint looks like this:

```
export const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    price: '9.99',
    productType: 'single-card',
    runtime: 1800,
    title: '5-Minute Stories: In the Wild',
    ageRange: [4, 7],
    author: 'Yoto',
    availableForSale: true,
    contentType: ['Animal Stories', 'Stories'],
    description:
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
    flag: 'New to Yoto',
    handle: '5-minute-stories-in-the-wild',
    imgSet: {
      sm: {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/300',
      },
      md: {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/768',
      },
      lg: {
        src: 'https://picsum.photos/1280',
      },
      alt: null,
    },
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test axios in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest)

Comment: specifically you are actually not mocking axios because you are not having `jest.mock("axios");` in your code at the right place, it needs to be in the test file.

Comment: I've tried that and it still isn't working

Comment: it's not just that, it was a starting point. look at the question above for more info how to set it up