# How to write unit test for antd table using React and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, antd

I am trying to write unit test using React and jest but I am not able to proceed:-
1)To mock data using jest axios.
2)To verify the table has rendered the mock data and expect them.
If you have any ideas or solution to writing unit test for antd design table and axios.get . Please let me know. Thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table, Tag } from 'antd';

const TableData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getData')
      .then(response => {
        const formattedData = response.data.map(item => ({
          key: item.id, // Assuming each item has a unique identifier like 'id'
          name: item.name,
          age: item.age,
          address: item.address,
          tags: item.tags,
        }));
        setData(formattedData);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
    },
    {
      title: 'Tags',
      key: 'tags',
      dataIndex: 'tags',
      render: (_, { tags }) => (
        <>
          {tags.map((tag) => {
            let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
            if (tag === 'loser') {
              color = 'volcano';
            }
            return (
              <Tag color={color} key={tag}>
                {tag.toUpperCase()}
              </Tag>
            );
          })}
        </>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={true} />
  );
};

export default TableData;
```

I tried something like this below but I am not able to populate the table with data.

```
jest.mock("axios");

const mockResponse = {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    tags: ['nice', 'developer'],
  }

it('renders table with data',async()=> {
axios.get.mockImplementation(()=> Promise.resolve(mockResponse));
render(<TableData />
screen.debug();
await waitFor(()=> {
expect(screen.getByText('John Brown')).toBeInTheDocument();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific to ant table it self in terms of jest unit test. Just mock axio check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016033/how-do-i-test-axios-in-jest).

Comment: I tried the above implementation but I am getting an error window.matchMedia is not a function.

Comment: can you https://codesandbox.io/ minimal example ?